# I don't know how log out in my app

Tags: ionic2

My first page in my app is for login so... when user access, go to the main page. My code for navigate is like this:

```
this.navController.setRoot(Principal, {
      param1: 'usuario000'
});
```

My question is, if I'm in the main page and user want to log out and I need to go to the login page again how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.navController.setRoot(LoginPage)
```

This will clear your navigation stack and bring you to your login page. Call this is your logout function and clear the Storage if you use it to save userdata.